# Tronscan transactions python3

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, etherscan, python

I try get transaction on tronscan.

```
from tronapi import Tron
from tronapi import HttpProvider

full_node = HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io')
solidity_node = HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io')
event_server = HttpProvider('https://api.trongrid.io')
tron = Tron(full_node=full_node,
            solidity_node=solidity_node,
            event_server=event_server)



result = tron.trx.get_transaction_info('ec1fc447e25ae5e5534f57c13c24615f1fb133ff73bb048619e65b13b17e3f10')
print(result)

{'id': 'ec1fc447e25ae5e5534f57c13c24615f1fb133ff73bb048619e65b13b17e3f10', 'fee': 4148340, 'blockNumber': 30749100, 'blockTimeStamp': 1622705961000, 'contractResult': ['0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'], 'contract_address': '41a614f803b6fd780986a42c78ec9c7f77e6ded13c', 'receipt': {'energy_fee': 4148340, 'energy_usage_total': 29631, 'net_usage': 345, 'result': 'SUCCESS'}, 'log': [{'address': 'a614f803b6fd780986a42c78ec9c7f77e6ded13c', 'topics': ['ddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef', '00000000000000000000000044ca4fc2c5485c3fc83d29a97e4b9324b5200662', '0000000000000000000000004d42001febc74537d659763242b1cd22645dc465'], 'data': '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000164cb1c80'}]}
```

Tell me please, how can i get value of the transaction, 5690 USDT?